# if user has a certain role then display image

Tags: user-roles

so close to figuring this out, or not I'm not to sure! Basically what I want to do is on the authors page (so outside the loop) if a user role is an editor I want to display a little badge (but just outputting their name and role at the mo) in their profile. I have:

functions.php:

```
function get_user_role($id)
{
    $user = new WP_User($id);
    return array_shift($user->roles);
}
```

and

author.php:

```
<?php
global $post;
$aid = $post->post_author;
if ($userlevel == '2') {
echo get_the_author_meta('user_nicename', $aid).' | '.get_user_role($aid);
}

?>
```

But doesn't seem to work, any ideas?

Comment: Please follow up on your other questions. You're already in a position where most people will stay away from answering further ones.

Comment: Any progress on this question?

Answer (score 1):

In your template:

```
// rolename could for e.g. be 'editor' or 'author' or 'administrator'
author_can( get_the_ID(), 'rolename' ) AND print "<img src='...' alt='A kool badge!' />";
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but would this not display for the logged in user and not the author of the profile?

Comment: @david Yes, you were right. Code fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Get all the editors first and then loop over them.

```
$users = get_users(array('role' => 'editor'));
//foreach user,
//your badge code
```

Does this help?

Comment: thanks for the reply but don't seem to get anything with that, using: if(current_user_can('editor')){
echo 'hello world ';
}

Comment: Are you logged in with that role? If you're logged in as administrator, try replacing `editor` with `administrator`. Do you want the code to run for logged in users only or any user with the editor role?

Comment: also wouldn't current_user_can only work if you were logged in as an editor, I want to display someone an editor to people visiting the site

Comment: Okay... then you may have to get the users list first, then check their role which is in the users object and do the stuff.